# Parameter 0 of constructor in jpa.adapter.SpringJpaAdapter required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test my controller, in my test class when I annotate it with `@SpringBootTest(classes = BootloaderApplicationLauncher.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` my test pass but when I try to annotate it with `@WebMvcTest(controllers = ReleveBancaireControllerImpl.class)` my application throws this exception:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in persistence.jpa.adapter.ReleveBancaireSpringJpaAdapter required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

I using maven multi modules.
I added all my configuration when I start the application works fine.
I just want to test my controller with `@WebMvcTest`
Spring boot version: 2.3.1.RELEASE
hibernate-entitymanager version: 5.0.0.Final
Hibernate-core version: 5.6.5.Final

Full exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'releveBancaireRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3c81cd82' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3c81cd82': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3c81cd82': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46461367/10042529 https://stackoverflow.com/a/47351315/10042529 These two answers might help you